# SignalR client get 403 forbidden error when jwt cookie expire

Tags: asp.net, authentication, signalr, jwt

My SignalR app use JWT authentication cookie for authentication. For testing I set the jwt exp payload to 3 min.

I tested in Chrome browser, transport using serverSentEvent.

I have a button on page which will trigger Hub's server method.

After 3 min, when I click on the button. The Hub will response 403 forbidden error. I guess it is because my jwt token expired.

However if then I reload the page, the hub still connected and started. The page still use the same cookie sent to server. When I click on the button to trigger server's method. This time it will not return 403 error. The server method still get called. But inside the server method, the Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false.

I can't understand why on the first load will trigger 403 error, but not on the reloaded page.

I want to catch the unauthorize access to signalr, if the jwk token is expired or contain invalid data, I will redirect to login page.